# `cache-control: max-age=0` in http request

Tags: http, cache-control

I have one question: suppose in each http request there is a `cache-control: max-age=0` header, so each request will go all the way to the origin web server.
Does it mean CDN is not useful anymore if all requests are like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the max-age to 0, you effectively expire your page in your CDN edge cache immediately. Therefore, your CDN always hit your origin and render the CDN useless as you suggested.

Noticed from your other question that you are using Akamai. If so, then you can use the `Edge-Control` header to override your `cache-control` if you don't have direct control over that value, but still want to be able to leverage CDN functionality.

Comment: hi,Jason                                                                                                              I got your suggestion.

Comment: Any chance that's a chrome or some other level of caching? If reached the CDN, it should have respected the maxage and thus not sent the 304, but I've seen even browsers or network appliances like an f5 or something also provide caching and thus the 304 without reaching the edge.

Comment: I tested some beahviors of browser 1: after cache expired in browser,I open a new windows to enter the link,browser sends "If-Modified-Since:" header to outside,and got an http 304  2:if browser cache is not expired ,I use "F5" to refresh,browser sends "If-Modified-Since:+Cache-Control:max-age=0" header to outside,and got an http 304.

Comment: my question is : the first request is served by akamai (akamai doesn't talk to origin server once cache in akamai is not expired since there is other request which refresh this content),but the 2nd request goes all the way to origin  since there is max-age=0. and the 1st request is how akamai serve the client in most case,am I right?

Comment: I use chrome as the test browser

Comment: That makes more sense - I thought you were sending the cache-control on your initial request as well. Chrome (and many other browsers) are built now that when you press F5 (or ctrl-f5) to force a refresh by inserting the cache-control header into your request. This is not the normal browsing pattern of a user, and it appears Akamai is serving the client in most cases.

Comment: ha. I am just testing how browser cache work in an Akamai enabled env.  so can I conclude that after cache expires in browser,akamai begins to serve If-Modified-Since: rquest from the second request(since the first request will force akamai to talk to origin when cache expires both in akamai and end user's browser) in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

from other post:
When sent by the user agent

I believe shahkalpesh's answer applies to the user agent side. You can also look at 13.2.6 Disambiguating Multiple Responses.

If a user agent sends a request with Cache-Control: max-age=0 (aka. "end-to-end revalidation"), then each cache along the way will revalidate its cache entry (eg. with the If-Not-Modified header) all the way to the origin server. If the reply is then 304 (Not Modified), the cached entity can be used.

On the other hand, sending a request with Cache-Control: no-cache (aka. "end-to-end reload") doesn't revalidate and the server MUST NOT use a cached copy when responding.

It makes sense and match my result. 
when cache is not expired in chrome,it will send request to CDN,CDN will query this with if-modified-since with origin ,then serve the end user.